# Getting larger horizontal dots

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I was creating some graphs related to sets in latex (cartesian graphs, arrow graphs and directed graphs). Now I noticed that `\Huge\vdots` will produce larger than normal vertical dots (although I still think they are a bit small, but that's not the issue here), but `\Huge\cdots` does not.

My primary question is, how could I get larger horizontal dots? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

does

```
\[\bullet\bullet\bullet\]
```

do what you want?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you :) Also, out of curiosity, do you why the font size affects `\vdots` but not `\cdots`?

Comment: @MaienM Size changes don't work as one might expect in math mode; but the `\vdots` are built with boxes where the size change has effect.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. That also explains why `\ddots` acts like `\vdots`, makes sense for that to use boxes as well. Thanks :)